# Tooltip on click hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a WordPress website where I use a tooltip to show when a user hovers over an icon. Now on mobile, I want the hover function to be done with a clicked function so I created a jQuery to handle it. I'm new to jQuery so that is probably the issue, or I'm doing it wrong and I can do it in another way. The issue is now that wont all the the tooltip-text be active no one someone clicks one tooltip icon?

It works with CSS to just use `display: block/none` but I want the click function to work too. And then style it with `opacity` and `transition`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tooltip').clicked(function() {
    $('.tooltiptext').addClass("tooltip-clicked");
  })
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip-text {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tooltip-clicked {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="tooltip">
  <p class="tooltip-text">lorem ipsum...</p>
</i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modify your css content to make it clickable and simple enough to tell the difference and modify your jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.tooltip').click(function (){
  $('.tooltip').addClass("tooltip-clicked");
 })
})
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.tooltip').click(function (){
  $('.tooltip').addClass("tooltip-clicked");
 })
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip:hover {
 color:green;
}

.tooltip.tooltip-clicked:hover {
 color:blue;
}

.tooltip-clicked {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="tooltip">
 <p class="tooltip-text">lorem ipsum...</p>
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
 jQuery('.tooltip').clicked(function (){
```

change the `clicked` to `click` and `tooltiptext` to `tooltip-text` like:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.tooltip').click(function (){
    $('.tooltip-text').addClass("tooltip-clicked");
    // put your tooltip logic here
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip-clicked {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="tooltip">
 <p class="tooltip-text">lorem ipsum...</p>
</i>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! May I ask how one would do to make only the specifically clicked tooltip text show, and not all at once when one is clicked? I know it has to do with maybe the data attribute or something like that but how would one best do it?